# Basis of linear operator in the space of square matrices of size 3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In the space of square matrices of size 3 set an operator $F(A)=AI$ (I -is a matrix of all ones). Find a matrix of this operator using an arbitrary basis.

I understood, that $\mathbf{Im}$ $F$ is just matrices with 3 equal numbers in a row (a sum of this row in A). So I tried to use a basis of permutation matrices, but I even don't understand the shape of the matrix which I should look for.

Comment: So $\;F=Id\;$, namely: it is just the identity map ? Since $\;AI=A\;$ ...If this is what you meant the answer is trivial...and a matrix representing $\;F\;$ is of order $\;9\times9\;$, if you meant that the space on which it acts is the set of all square matrices of order $\;3\times3\;$ .

Comment: Matrix I is all filed by ones, not only main diagonal.